# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when using CASE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COL_VALUE) = 1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC, COL_VALUE) * 1000
  ELSE COL_VALUE 
END AS [COL_VALUE]
FROM Table
```

The original data type is varchar that is why I convert `COL_VALUE` to `numeric`.
It seems like something wrong with `ELSE statement`, when I execute the query without `ELSE statement` the `non-numeric` value will become `NULL`. I check whether or not the column is numeric, if it is numeric then multiply by 1000, if not numeric then return original value. There are few non-numeric values like:

```
23`, 34/, 34=4.
```

Comment: so, according to your `CASE` expression, if the value of the column is numeric, you want to return a numeric data type, and if it's not numeric, to return another data type. A column has to be of a single data type

Comment: All of the paths in your `CASE` must resolve to the same type.  If `COL_VALUE` has the possibility of being a `VARCHAR`, you need to make your first path return a `VARCHAR` as well, like, `CAST(CONVERT(NUMERIC, COL_VALUE) * 1000) AS NVARCHAR)`

Comment: As you are on 2012 you should use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `ISNUMERIC` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are returning numeric and non  umeric values you shoud cast everything back to `varchar`. Also use `try_cast` function because `isnumeric` function will return sometimes true when you have dollar sign in your string for example and `convert` function will fail:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(COL_VALUE AS NUMERIC) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CAST(CAST(COL_VALUE AS NUMERIC) * 1000 AS VARCHAR(100))
            ELSE COL_VALUE 
       END AS [COL_VALUE]
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COL_VALUE) = 1 THEN Convert(varchar(50), CONVERT(NUMERIC, COL_VALUE) * 1000)
  ELSE COL_VALUE 
END AS [COL_VALUE]
FROM Table
```